# How to close `navigator.notification.alert` messages without clicking the buttons

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, navigator

How to close `navigator.notification.alert` messages without clicking the buttons in it. I want to close all messages that created when an action done(like calling a `closeAllMessages()` method).

```
 navigator.notification.alert('message', null, "Alert", "OK");
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to do what you want with the standard `navigator.notification.alert`. Your options are find a plugin to do what you want. Build a plugin to do what you want. -Best of Luck